# How to make my .NET Core 5 application compile with .NET Core 5 in VS 2022?

Tags: c#, .net-5, visual-studio-2022

I have a .NET Core 5 console application:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

When I compile it in VS2022, it seems to use .NET Core 7 to do so, because I see this in the build output:

> 1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(257,5):
>
> message NETSDK1057: You are using a preview version of .NET. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-support-policy

How can I tell Visual Studio to use .NET Core 5 to compile this project?

.NET 5 is installed on my machine:

```
PS B:\...> dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.413 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

<sub>Yes, I'm aware that .NET Core 5 is outdated.</sub>

<sub>Exact version is Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0 Preview 6</sub>

SLN file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.4.33027.239
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "NetCore5Console", "ConsoleNetCore5\NetCore5Console.csproj", "{43DE576A-1052-4AC5-B612-D88D9D6624B6}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {43DE576A-1052-4AC5-B612-D88D9D6624B6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {43DE576A-1052-4AC5-B612-D88D9D6624B6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {EF895EC5-66AD-4B5A-ACFF-594C848D2311}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

CSPROJ file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      <CheckEolTargetFramework>false</CheckEolTargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleNetCore5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the csproj file? I am able to compile .net 5 project in VS 22 17.4 preview 6 version

Comment: @viveknuna: do you have .NET Core 7 installed? IMHO it happens since I have .NET Core 7 installed. Before that, it was ok

Comment: thankfully I have nt installed .net 7 yet and if this could be the problem, you have saved me :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `global.json` file along side your solution file specifying which SDK version you want to use.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.413",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Comment: Thanks. "The .NET SDK looks for a global.json file in the current working directory" - in "the working directory"? The working directory of what? Devenv.exe? That means I can't have a Core 5 and Core 7 project in parallel?

Comment: put it along side your sln file

Comment: In which case I can't have a Core 5 and Core 7 project in the same solution... Okay, maybe I'll ask another question for that. I didn't specify that, because I would never think of such a crazy idea having this kind of configuration on a solution level. Microsoft... In C++ you can specify C++14 for Debug and C++20 for Release build, and in .NET they go the opposite direction. Argh!