# How to make my two .NET Core projects compile with their own version of .NET Core in VS 2022?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-5, visual-studio-2022

Essentially the same problem [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327516/how-to-make-my-net-core-5-application-compile-with-net-core-5-in-vs-2022), but in addition I have a .NET Core 6 project in the same solution that shall be compiled with .NET Core 6, while the .NET Core 5 Project shall be compiled with .NET Core 5.

I've tried

- putting a `global.json` into each directory where the projects are located. In that case, they will all be compiled with .NET Core 7.

Answer (score 0):

The following similar solution fixes your issue that I think. By selecting your each project create a `global.json` file by writing `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version your-sdk-version`. It generates the following file for example,

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.2"
  }
}
```

To see what version exactly you need, you can run `dotnet --list-sdks` showing version with corresponding paths. Having created this `global.json` file, running `dotnet --version` now returns `6.0.2`. And if we, *to just test*, do a `dotnet new` console we'll see that the generated `.csproj` targets the 6.0.2 runtime, as we'd expect:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I don't know any other way to carry out your request than using `global.json` that each project must have in in this case.

Comment: A link to what microsoft has to say about [global-json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) seems to be worthful/useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting your each project"? No matter what I select, when I open the terminal (developer shell), nothing changes.

Comment: Where should those `global.json` files go? I tried putting them into the directory of the project, each, but that doesn't work.